# MySQL require unique column value dependent on linked column

Tags: mysql

Sorry if this question has been asked before, however I can't seem to find what I am looking for. (Outside of actually letting PHP do the checking for me).

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
ukey | dvar | dval
123   is_act   true
123   is_act   true
321   is_act   true
321   active   false
```

What I would like to do is set a `unique` constraint on `dvar` based on `ukey`

A `dvar` and `ukey` row pair MUST be unique

So in my test case the table should *actually* only look like:

```
ukey | dvar | dval
123   is_act   true
321   is_act   true
321   active   false
```

I am already checking in the database against a `ukey` / `dvar` combo, however I would like to know if what I am asking is possible to constrain inside of `MySQL`

Comment: "A single ukey may only be attached to unique dvar"... but according to your "should look like" example, `321` is attached to `is_act` and `active`

Comment: @uueerdo yes, that is a unique `ukey` and `dvar` row. Editing for less confusion.

Comment: Then Rahul's answer below should be just what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I would like to do is set a unique constraint on dvar based on
>   ukey

Yes, either make (dvar, ukey) as primary key saying

```
PRIMARY KEY (dvar, ukey)
```

Or, create a UNIQUE Key constraint on both the column.

```
ALTER TABLE test
   ADD CONSTRAINT uniqueconstraint UNIQUE(dvar, ukey);
```

Comment: Would this work since `dvar` by itself is not required to be unique. The only event `dvar` is unique is when tested against `ukey`. Two `ukey`s can have the same dvar, but the same `ukey` may not have non-unique `dvar`s

Comment: @HydraIO A unique constraint on multiple fields only enforces that the combinations of those fields' values must be unique (except for NULL), not that each field's value must be unique independently.

Comment: @rahul thank you. The `UNIQUE` on both cols solved the issue.

Comment: @HydraIO, that's why I have made them as composite key. See the answer. means, by combination they should be unique.